render_to_string function not displaying context variables
I am trying to implement the render_to_string function in a Django project.
I have an HTML template (strategy.html) containing many Django Template Language variables and 'if conditions' and would like to save the rendered output in a DB model.
The output is saved in the db model but the context variables are ignored.
The action has to be triggered once the 'Save' button is clicked (see code below).
Important note: the DTL variables and 'if conditions' are correctly displayed when using the render function by clicking the 'Generate' button.
Here is the views.py file:
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from strategiesAPI.models import strategiesList


@login_required
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Get form information
        starttime = request.POST.get("starttime")
        endtime = request.POST.get("endtime")
        trigger = request.POST.get("trigger")
        entrieslimit = request.POST.get("entrieslimit")
        direction = request.POST.get("direction")
        pattern = request.POST.get("pattern")
        stoploss = request.POST.get("stoploss")
        takeprofit = request.POST.get("takeprofit")
        tradeliquid = request.POST.get("tradeliquid")

        # Context variables for the render and render_to_string function 
        content = {
                "starttime": starttime, 
                "endtime": endtime, 
                "trigger": trigger, 
                "entrieslimit": entrieslimit, 
                "direction": direction, 
                "pattern": pattern, 
                "stoploss": stoploss, 
                "takeprofit": takeprofit, 
                "tradeliquid": tradeliquid
                    }
        
        # Action based on the button pressed inside the index.html template

        # GENERATE button
        if request.POST['button'] == 'Generate':
            # Write strategy on the right side of the page using the user's inputs
            return render(request, "composer/index.html", content)

        # SAVE button
        if request.POST['button'] == 'Save':
            # Save the strategy DTL output into the db model using the render_to_string function
            strategy_html = render_to_string("composer/strategy.html", content)
            strategiesList.objects.create(script=strategy_html)
            return render(request, "composer/index.html")
    else:
        return render(request, "composer/index.html")

Below I will paste what is saved in the db model followed by the strategy.html file containing the DTL variables and 'if conditions' (which are ignored)
<!-------------------------------------- Right-side EasyLanguage & DTL output -------------------------------------->

<div class="right" id="output" style="font-size: 11px;">
    // EasyLanguage code composer by ©SOACM. All rights reserved // <br>
    <br>

    <!-------------------------------------- Breakout -------------------------------------->
    
    <!-------------------------------------- Breakout end ----------------------------------->


    <!-------------------------------------- Reversal --------------------------------------->
    
    <!-------------------------------------- Reversal end ------------------------------------->
</div>

<!-------------------------------------- Right-side EasyLanguage & DTL output -------------------------------------->

<div class="right" id="output" style="font-size: 11px;">
    // EasyLanguage code composer by ©SOACM. All rights reserved // <br>
    <br>

    <!-------------------------------------- Breakout -------------------------------------->
    {% if trigger == "breakout" %}
        input: StartTime({{ starttime }}), EndTime({{ endtime }}), MyStopLoss({{ stoploss }}), MyTakeProfit({{ takeprofit }}); <br>
        var: bool MyTime(False), int MP(0); <br>
            MP = MarketPosition; <br>
            MyTime = False; <br>
            if Time >= StartTime and Time <= EndTime and EntriesToday(date[0]) < 1 then MyTime = True; <br>
            <br>
            
            {% if pattern == "none" %}
            // Levels <br>
            if date <> date[1] then begin <br>
            var: highd1(0), lowd1(0); <br>
            highd1 = HighS(1); <br>
            lowd1 = LowS(1); <br>
            end; <br>
            {% endif %}
            <br>
            

EDIT: solution might be related to Django's security features like mark_safe function which can be found here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.html
Any suggestion can help.

'breakout' corresponds to multiple choice dropdowns that the user can select. They are located in the main index.html template (strategy.html is included in index.html). As mentioned in my post, these variables are correctly displayed when using the render function.
